# php for each and xml

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to understand the code bellow which gets an XML and coverts it to JSON. But not quiet sure how it works.

```
function splicing_json($xml){
    $str='';
    foreach($xml->children() as $child)
    {
        if(count($child)===0){
            $str .= '"'.$child->getName().'":"'.$child.'",';
        }else if(count($child)>0){
            $str .= '"' . $child->getName() . '":{';
            foreach($child->children() as $val){
                if(count($val)>0) {
                    $str .='"' . $val->getName() . '":{'.splicing_json($val).'},';
                }else if(count($val)===0){
                    $str .= '"' . $val->getName() . '":"'.$val.'",';
                }
            }
            $str .= '},';
        }
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow it down a bit? Are there any specific parts of it that you're having trouble with?

Comment: This is not good code. Never try and build your own formatted data, whether it's JSON, XML, or even CSV. Use the built-in tools like `json_encode()` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

splicing_json function foreachs the XML child nodes, it's not very efficent and it won't work if you've multiple XML nodes with the same name, but let's take this XML file as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <simple_text>Hi there!</simple_text>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <phone category="children">
     <owners category="children">
        <name>Mostafa</name>
        <address>Cairo</address>
     </owners>
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </phone>
  <game category="web">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </game>
</bookstore>
```

Child #1: simple_text is the first child node that will be processed by the function, it's a string value so `(count($child)===0)` will be true and it will be added to the json str as a string value `"simple_text":"Hi there!",`.

Child #2, second node that will be processed by the function is book, it's an array so `(count($child)>0)` will be true, the function then foreaches child nodes of the book node, and if any of its nodes is an array it will run recursively and process it again `if(count($val)>0)` , if not it will simply add the child node value the same way it did with Child #1 and then adds it to the str variable.

Child #3, this one will be processed the same way as Child #2, but it has a node called owners, which contains an array, `if(count($val)>0)` this statement will return true, which means it will be reprocessed by splicing_json and the same process will run again only on that node. the returned value by the function will then be added to the main str variable.

It's a simple recursive function that performs will iterate until all the nodes are processed.

if you decode the output it should look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [simple_text] => Hi there!
    [book] => Array
        (
            [title] => Everyday Italian
            [author] => Giada De Laurentiis
            [year] => 2005
            [price] => 30.00
        )

    [phone] => Array
        (
            [owners] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Mostafa
                    [address] => Cairo
                )

            [title] => Harry Potter
            [author] => J K. Rowling
            [year] => 2005
            [price] => 29.99
        )

    [game] => Array
        (
            [title] => Learning XML
            [author] => Erik T. Ray
            [year] => 2003
            [price] => 39.95
        )

)
```